# Is it possible to convert from varchar to numeric within a nested if statement in order to dynamically evaluate a parameter?

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to convert from varchar to numeric within a nested if statement in order to dynamically evaluate a parameter?

Below is code used to set the parameters used for my report.  @Season is the only parameter used in the report and drives the others used to build the related queries.  I am trying to evaluate @SP_Season using if statements for season 'F13', 'F14' and >= 'F15'.  I have F13 and F14 working but I cannot get F15 to work.  I think it should be something like this:

```
IF (CONVERT(NUMERIC,@SP_Season, >= 15)
```

But, this obviously isn't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(
@Season varchar(50) 
) 

WITH Recompile

as 

BEGIN 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Declare @SP_Season varchar(50) = @Season 
Declare @PriorSeason_1 varchar(50)
Declare @PriorSeason_2 varchar(50)
Declare @YR numeric 
Declare @Sport varchar (50)

SET @YR = (SELECT RIGHT (SEASON,2) FROM TK_SEASON WHERE SEASON = @SP_Season)
SET @Sport = (SELECT SUBSTRING(SEASON,1,LEN(SEASON)-2) FROM TK_SEASON WHERE SEASON = @SP_Season)
SET @PriorSeason_1 = (@Sport + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@YR - 1))
SET @PriorSeason_2 = (@Sport + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@YR - 2))
```

Comment: Do you just want to convert `F15` to a number `15`? Is `@Season` always a `F` followed by a number?

Comment: Yes.  The seasons are always characters followed by two numbers.  So Football 2013 is F13, Women's Basketball 2013 is WB13 and so on for other sports.

Comment: Ok, I will need to modify my answer slightly then. Done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the season being letters followed by 2 numbers, you can extract the 2 digits using `SUBSTRING` and then cast to a number type:

```
declare @Season as varchar(50) = 'WB13'

select CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@Season, LEN(@Season) - 1, 2))
```